# a href style How to change link

Tags: html, styles, href

How to disable or change the display of this link through the style. Help me please.

[image: link href]

Comment: That's part of the browser. You can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an `<a>` element if you do not want this behaviour. You cannot change it.

Instead, what you could do is have a `<p>` that uses the `onclick` event to send the user to your URL using JavaScript.

A working code might look like:

```
<p onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com'">Press here!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of the website but a overflow added by the browser, you can not change what it displays. If you want to disable it you could have it instead of a href, a onclick handler that changes the websites location, but this would not work when users have javascript disabled or tries to open it in a new tab.